# Scala Monad operation on iterators

Tags: scala, monads, transformation, traits

I am having trouble on my Char Source Scala program. The package to develop implements a notion of document source. A document source is similar to an iterator
but produces its contents either as characters or as words, whichever is most convenient to the underlying
application. As with iterators, words and characters are produced “on the fly” and are not stored. Correct
implementations of document sources should be able to

Trait CharSource: This trait represents the base type that can be modified my mixing in transformers. Its source of
characters is abstract. From it are derived words and from words, characters.
 handle large documents without loading them entirely
in memory.
A document source offers two methods:
• chars: produces the contents of the document as an iterator of characters;
• words: produces the contents of the document as an iterator of words.

**This is where I am having trouble with the monaid operator on an iterator. I attempted foreach and map.**

Class IteratorDocumentSource:

This class provides us with a default implementation of the type RichDocumentSource. It can be used to mix
in traits in various combinations and observe the results. Note that this class implements the full (“rich”)
document source interface, including the monadic operators.

```
package document

class IteratorDocumentSource(iterator: Iterator[Char]) extends CharSource 
with RichDocumentSource {

protected def source: Iterator[Char] = iterator

def foreach[A](f: (Char) => A): Unit = {
 val it = iterator
 for( x <- it ) yield f(x)
 }

def map(f: (Char) => Char): IteratorDocumentSource = {
 val it = iterator
 val n  = for( x <- it ) yield f(x)
 }

new IteratorDocumentSource(n)

def flatMap(f: (Char) => TraversableOnce[Char]): IteratorDocumentSource = 
???

def withFilter(f: (Char) => Boolean): IteratorDocumentSource = ???
}




// $Id: RichDocumentSource.scala 93 2017-03-26 18:46:10Z abcdef $

package document

/** A rich document source.
* It extends a regular document source with the so-called "monadic" 
functions:
* `foreach`, `withFilter`, `map` and `flatMap`.  Those operate at the 
''character'' level, not on
 * words.
 *
 * @see Iterator

 trait RichDocumentSource extends DocumentSource {

 /** Applies the given function to all the characters in the document. */
 def foreach[A](f: (Char) => A): Unit

  /** A new document obtained by applying the given transformation to all 
  the 
 characters of this
 * document.
 */
 def map(f: (Char) => Char): RichDocumentSource

 /** A new document obtained by applying the given transformation to all the 
 characters of this
 * document.
 */
 def flatMap(f: (Char) => TraversableOnce[Char]): RichDocumentSource

 /** A new document obtained by applying the given filter to all the 
 characters of this document.
 */
 def withFilter(f: (Char) => Boolean): RichDocumentSource
  }
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Where is your `Monoid` ? And where is this "trouble" ? You need to understand that this description does not convey the question which you wanted to ask in any understandable form. Please try to come up with a better description of your problem and only then someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Also... I can see that you mentioned `Monoid` and `Monad` and `Monadic operators` in this question. And reading this description I feel that you do not really understand any of these concepts. So, it will be more helpful if you try to explain your problem in simpler words without using any of these terms.